# COM Error using CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Utilities.Conversion

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-server

My code:

```
var utility = new CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Utilities.Conversion();
var ortpstring = utility.ToString(orpt);
```

I get the following error:

```
{System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80040154): Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {08497EE6-2ABB-4E1A-A41E-37D2C26E72B6} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).
   at CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Utilities.Conversion.ToString(ISCDReportClientDocument m_rptClientDoc)
   at eSiteWeb.frmViewer2.InitializeCrystalReportRAS() in c:\Users\rarch\Development\Amsi-v7.5.2\Product\Production\eSiteWeb\frmviewer2.aspx.cs:line 203}
```

I am using Unmanaged RAS 2012 Embedded. The docs seem to indicate this is supported.

Does anyone know why I am getting this other than the obvious. What .dll/feature am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Shot in the dark, but, if the server is 64-bit, then in the IIS Manager on the server, make sure to set the application pool for your web application to allow 32-bit assemblies. Although it's been deployed to a 64-bit system, it doesn't mean all the referenced assemblies are 64-bit Crystal Reports assemblies because they are mainly wrappers to a collection of legacy DLLs, some of which are 32-bit.

To do this, you'll also need to deploy the 32-bit redistributable to your 64-bit server (so you need to install both 64-bit and 32-bit).

Comment: we already run in 32-bit mode since our app contains legacy VB6 com objects.

Comment: Ok I thought it worth a mention anyway. Did you check IIS user permissions to use COM?

Comment: As I said, the problem is I don't even have that COM object registered. I expect something needed isn't installed but I don't know what that is.

Comment: I understand, it's just that it's the same error you get if IIS doesn't have permission to use COM.